# How to properly escape this JSP code to avoid Stored XSS valnerabilities?

Tags: java, security, jsp, xss, struts

These are flagged as having "Stored XSS vulnerabilities". Need to know how to properly escape the following to address this type of cross site scripting vulnerability?

```
out.print("<td headers=\""+headerIDs.get(i-1)+"\""+ (wrap?"":"nowrap")+">"+StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)? value : "&nbsp;"+"</td>");

out.print("<td headers=\""+headerIDs.get(i-1)+"\""+ (wrap?"":"nowrap")+">"+StringUtils.escapeXML(value, "&nbsp;")+"</td>");
```

I've seen a couple possible solutions but not sure which one is the better one?

> ```
> StringUtils.renderSafeHtml(...)
> ```

> ```
> Encoder.forHtml(...)
> ```

My teammates are using `renderSafeHtml(...)` to address the other kinds of XSS vulnerabilities in our code, so I prefer to use this one. However, all the examples I've seen online suggest `Encoder.forHtml(...)` for "Stored XSS".

Bear in mind `org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils.htmlEscape` is not an option since we use Struts.

Comment: What a Struts version do you use?

Comment: Look at them both and pick one, or just use the one y'all are already using. Seems like this is more rabbit-holing than really necessary if either does what you need.